# Resolving a promise in Mobx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I have a fetch request in a mobx store that looks like this:

```
getAllLegoParts = action("get all lego", () => {
 this.legoParts = fromPromise(
   fetch("http://localhost:8000/LegoPieces", {
     cache: "no-store"
   }).then(response => response.json())
 );
});
```

this.legoParts is in a constructor that looks like this:

```
constructor() {
extendObservable(this, {
  // store
  legoParts: fromPromise.resolve([]),
  piece: "",
  type: "",
  startDate: "",
  endDate: ""
 });
}
```

I'm trying to access the value of the array that should be in legoParts.  However when I console log legoParts, I get a bunch of data, including the PromiseStatus (resolved) and the PromiseValue.  How can I simply access the promise value?  I'm also confused because although the PromiseStatus says resolved, the beginning of the object says

```
 Promise{<pending>....
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the official [docs](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-utils#frompromise), `fromPromise` creates a wrapper, and it's `.value` property contains the resolved value

Comment: Thanks, I've checked the value and its undefined, and I've checked state and its pending (which would explain the value!).  But how can I make it resolved?  Thanks!

Comment: That will happen automatically in the future, once the promise resolves.